# Jmeter extract data from Sampler Result

Tags: jmeter

I need extract some string from Sampler Result, for example `Latency:`. How can i do that? Using regex function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to extract the Latency using Regular Expression Extractor, if you need this metric as a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) I would rather suggest going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
def latency = prev.getLatency()
vars.put('status', latency as String)
```

where:

- `prev` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance
- `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

See [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for the aforementioned classes to see the available properties and functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Demo:

[image]

the value can be referred as `${status}` where required

Comment: Ok, and how about Error Counter?